# Type error doesn't show up when it should

Tags: angular

I'm wondering why is this not showing me any type error while it obviously should. Instead of getting the type error, I'm getting the result of:

Hello 34

Here's my code:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'test',
    template: `
        <h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>
    `
})

export class TestComponent {
    name:string = 'John Doe';

    constructor(){
        this.name = 34;
    }
}
```

Am I getting this wrong or what?!

Using Angular 4 and Chrome browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes should  get an error as

```
 'Type '34' is not assignable to type 'string'.'
```

To see the Lint error, you should enable the following in tslint.config

**`"variable-name": false`**

Comment: No shit :D That's what I expect to get, but instead of it, I'm getting "Hello 34". Any ideas why?

Comment: What is the IDE , did you add a tslint rule?

Comment: It is compiled because it does not matter the type is

Comment: Didn't add anything, but perhaps it's indeed because of the IDE? I'm using the latest Visual Studio Code

Comment: So I need to specify it somehow? ...how, then?! where do I declare it

Comment: Check the tslint config

Comment: I THINK I FOUND IT! :) the `"variable-name": false,` should be true ! Thanks buddy! :)